# Codeigniter Say Illegal offset type in isset or empty when I update multiple cart item

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeignter cart.I want to update my cart page with multiple cart item.
I send the rowid and qty as an arry. 
  here is my form

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>cart/update_cartpage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <td class=" product-price"><span class="amount"><span class="money"><?php echo $values['price'];?></span></span>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $values['rowid']?>" name="rowid[]" ></td>  
                  <td><span>
                  <div class=" cart-plus-minus cart_page">   

                    <div class="dec qtybutton ">-</div>    
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $values['qty'];?>"  name="qty[]"  id="qty" class="qty minhaj_update test">
                    <div class="inc qtybutton " >+</div>                        
                    </div></span>                       
                  </td>
                  <td class=" product-subtotal"><span class="money" data-currency-usd="<?php echo $values['subtotal'];?>"><?php echo $values['subtotal'];?></span></td>
                  <td class=" product-remove cartrmove" data-id="<?php echo $values['rowid']?>"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php $i++; } ;?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>              
          <div class="row table-responsive_bottom">                
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7">
              <div class="buttons-carts">
                 <input class="theme-default-button" type="submit" value="Update Cart">                  
                 <a href="<?=base_url();?>">Continue Shopping</a> 
</div></form>`
```

Here is my controller

```
    public function update_cartpage()
   {


  $roids=$this->input->post('rowid',true);
 $gty=$this->input->post('qty',true);


 if (!empty($roids)) {

  $data = array(
              'rowid' => $roids,
               'qty'     => $gty
            );


  /*  print_r($data);
  exit; */ 
  $this->cart->update($data);
 } else{
     echo "sorry";
     exit;       
 }
```

Comment: Why there is `true` on your post? Try to change `$roids=$this->input->post('rowid',true);` to `$roids=$this->input->post('rowid');`

Comment: I try this but not working

Comment: And also you should use `isset` on your if statement to check if the POST data is submitted. I think empty will not suits for that because it reads `array`

Comment: 'isset' also not  working

Comment: Important

FYI: **The Cart library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility.** as in https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code: Try to use `foreach` loop to cast the data in array variable.

You can remove `true` on your posted data.

```
 public function update_cartpage()
   {

      $roids=$this->input->post('rowid');
      $gty=$this->input->post('qty');

 if (!empty($roids)) {

   foreach($roids as $index=> $val ) {
      $data = array(
              'rowid' => $val ,
               'qty'    => $gty[$index]
            );

       $this->cart->update($data);
     }




  } else{
     echo "sorry";
     exit;       
  }
```

**OR you can use array_combine()**

```
  public function update_cartpage()
   {

      $roids=$this->input->post('rowid');
      $gty=$this->input->post('qty');

 if (!empty($roids)) {

   foreach(array_combine($roids, $qty) as $roid=> $qty) {
      $data = array(
              'rowid' => $roid,
               'qty'    => $qty
            );

      $this->cart->update($data);
     }



  } else{
     echo "sorry";
     exit;       
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it going to same result

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the `$this->cart->update($data);` inside the loop. The answer is now edited.

Comment: Can you consider this as answered? Thank you